# Loose coupling through XSD

Tags: java, xml, parsing, architecture, jaxb

I don't want to modify my java code every time i modify my XSD or at least while modifying the existing validation rules in XSD.Is there any parser in Java to do so. Or any other design to achieve this.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that the main idea behind the design of SOAP?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need to modify your Java Code while you make changes to XSD. If you are using the XML validator from library, its only task is to validate incoming xml file against the specified XSD. If XSD changes, the incoming XML file should be changed to validate against the XSD and not the Java code.
Not sure if i am mis-understanding your question.

Thanks!

Comment: So who will use XSD, in my case it is going to be one among JAXB, XMLBeans, JIBX etc .

Comment: It does not matter. As long as you have a external file .xsd which is being used at various places in the code. If XSD schema file changes, incoming xml should be changed accordingly to get validated.

Comment: oh kool then, so you mean even if we modify the XSD, parser is still going to work without binding the modified schema .so nice , i couldn't realize this.could you please elaborate little more on this.

Comment: Task of parser is pretty simple. Read the XSD file, form xml tree out of it. Read the incoming xml file, and validate the same against it. If the XSD changes, and XML not, validation will fail. If XML also changes accordingly, Validation succeeds.

Comment: thanks man, i am slowly getting your point.by the way binding a schema means generating set of Java classes that represent the schema.Could you please explain me how should we not generate such set of Java classes after modifying the XSD.

Comment: Gotcha. So there is a dependency between Schema and JAXB. But we should not actually modify the code but let the framework do this for us. To get this, whenever you change XSD schema, you should run JAXB's xjc command to create updated Binding class. Checkout here : http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java/jaxb/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-using-jaxb-xjc-command/

Comment: Nice to see that you Gotcha, this finally worth my effort on posting  above comments step by step. In fact i have been using XJC since long time. I posted this question if somebody can provide a solution for my use case.